# how to synch up Django application database to local directory on my pc

Tags: html, django, database

My Django Application is running on "http://culhapartners.pythonanywhere.com/Front/Front_End"

Actually all this data for the website is in Django database on this online server.

My problem is "I want to run this website even if there is not internet connectivity"

how to move all database data to local pc directory?

Any suggestion as a starting point

Thank you
Regards
Noman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a data dump with the [`dumpdata` management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-app-label-app-label-app-label-model), then transfer this file to your local computer. Then you can load this data with the appropriately named [`loaddata` command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#loaddata-fixture-fixture).

Or, if its a lightweight website and you are using sqlite, you can just copy the database file to your local machine.

Comment: Thanks @BurhanKhalid. I will study these areas. Thanks once again